# Which is better stylistically in a pass-by-reference language. Returning a variable and reassigning, or not returning a variable?

Tags: python, coding-style

For example: (Not reassigning)

```
def doStuff(someDictionary):
    addValue(someDictionary)
    removeSomething(someDictionary)

someDictionary = {1 : 'A', 2 : 'B'}
doStuff(someDictionary)
print(someDictionary)
```

Or (Reassigning)

```
def doStuff(someDictionary):
    someDictionaryAdded = addValue(someDictionary)
    someDictionaryRemoved = removeSomething(someDictionaryAdded)
    return someDictionaryRemoved

someDictionary = {1 : 'A', 2 : 'B'}
someDictionaryStuffHappened = doStuff(someDictionary)
print(someDictionaryStuffHappened)
```

Which of these 2 methods are better in terms of style and clarity? Is there a significant performance difference that i need to consider as well?

Thank you.

Comment: Completely depends on what you want to do. You want an in-place operation: you are using 1) you don't: you are using 2).